# Nginx config: POST request does not go through (301 redirect)

Tags: nginx

POST requests work properly with the following config (with no redirect to any other location):

```
server {
    listen 80 default;

    client_max_body_size 108M;

    root /app/public;
    index index.php;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Once I move it to another location - it stops working (it just redirects "POST /v1/notifications HTTP/1.1" 301"):

```
server {
    listen 80;

    client_max_body_size 108M;
    root /app/public;
    index index.php;

    location /v1/notifications {
        alias /app/public;
        index index.php index.html;

        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^.*$ index.php last;
        }

        location ~* "\.php$" {
            fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
            index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    #this is for another app container
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://application:80;
        [.....];
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Should sth be added? Or it does not work this way at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default behaviour, as `/v1/notifications` now maps to the path `/app/public` which is a directory. You can inhibit the default behaviour by replacing your `if` block with a `try_files` statement.

For example:

```
location /v1/notifications {
    alias /app/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    try_files $uri /v1/notifications/index.php;    

    location ~* "\.php$" {
        ...
    }
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.